# Implementing `traverse` and `sequenceA`

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement `traverse` and `sequenceA` on my own:

Here's my implementation of `traverse'` in terms of `sequenceA`:

```
traverse' :: (Functor t, Foldable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
traverse' f x = sequenceA' $ fmap f x
```

However, I'm stuck on implementing `sequenceA`.

```
sequenceA' :: (Functor t, Foldable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
sequenceA' x = foldr (\a _ -> fmap helper a) (error "...") x
```

I used a placeholder for `b` (`error "..."`) - I'm not sure how to create a `b` given these types.

```
helper :: (Functor t, Foldable t) => a -> t a
helper x = error "TODO"
```

Also, I used the `helper` function to get this code to type-check. But, again, that's simply an `error` call.
Please give me a hint on how to generically implement `sequenceA`.

Comment: You can't implement sequenceA without traverse and you can't implement traverse without sequenceA.

Comment: `Traversable` is a stronger claim than just `Functor` and `Foldable`.  You _cannot_ define `traverse` or `sequenceA` in terms of `Functor` and `Foldable` functions alone, though you can define them in terms of each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given:

```hs
traverse' :: (Functor t, Foldable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
traverse' a2fb ta = sequenceA' (fmap a2fb ta)

sequenceA' :: (Functor t, Foldable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
sequenceA' tfa = _
```

An ideal use of holes! We give a name to all our parameters (no need to go pointfree and make our lives difficult just quite yet) and stick a hole where a definition should be. This yields:

```hs
src/Main.hs:8:14: Found hole ‘_’ with type: f (t a) …
```

We now cast around for a function that returns something like `f (t a)`. As luck would have it, `traverse'` does and now we can refine our hole to:

```hs
sequenceA' :: (Functor t, Foldable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
sequenceA' tfa = traverse _ _

src/Main.hs:8:27: Found hole ‘_’ with type: a0 -> f a …
src/Main.hs:8:29: Found hole ‘_’ with type: t a0 …
```

That first one looks messy, but we know something that fits the `t a0` for the second one, which is our `tfa`. Plug and chug:

```hs
sequenceA' :: (Functor t, Foldable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
sequenceA' tfa = traverse _ tfa

src/Main.hs:8:27: Found hole ‘_’ with type: f a -> f a …
```

Well, we know of a function with that signature, and that's `id`. So our final answer is:

```hs
traverse' :: (Functor t, Foldable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
traverse' a2fb ta = sequenceA' (fmap a2fb ta)

sequenceA' :: (Functor t, Foldable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
sequenceA' tfa = traverse id tfa
```

We can now go young, wild, and pointfree(-ish):

```hs
traverse' :: (Functor t, Foldable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
traverse' a2fb = sequenceA' . fmap a2fb

sequenceA' :: (Functor t, Foldable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
sequenceA' = traverse id
```

[Which matches the definitions in Prelude.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Data.Traversable.html#Traversable) ~holes~