# Traversable#mapM & sequence - Necessary?

Tags: haskell

[Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Traversable) presents Traversable:

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable t where
  traverse  :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
  sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
  mapM      ::       Monad m => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
  sequence  ::       Monad m => t (m a) -> m (t a)
```

> A good exercise is to figure out what the default implementations should be: given either traverse or sequenceA, how would you define the other three methods?

I came up with the following code that type-checks:

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => MyTraversable t where
  traverse'  :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
  traverse' = error "..."
  sequenceA' :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
  sequenceA' f = traverse' id f
  mapM      ::       Monad m => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
  mapM = traverse'
  sequence'  ::       Monad m => t (m a) -> m (t a)
  sequence' = sequenceA'
```

If my implementations of `mapM` and `sequence'` are correct, and, since every Monad is an Applicative:

```
λ: :i Monad
class Applicative m => Monad (m :: * -> *) where
...
```

then it's not clear to me why `mapM` and `sequence'` are even necessary. Why are they?

P.S. - Credit and my thanks to [haoformayor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3963/haoformayor) for helping me out with [`sequenceA`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460160/implementing-traverse-and-sequencea).

Comment: There was an embarrassing time when not every `Monad` was an `Applicative`.

Comment: You didn't ask about this, but you should *never* make a default class method that always produces an error. Just don't make a default in that case; GHC will warn if the method isn't defined in an instance. With a bogus default, users get no warning; things just blow up at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, there was a time when not every `Monad` was an `Applicative`.
Just recently (in `base-4.8` which shipped with GHC 7.10) the `Applicative` was made a superclass of `Monad`. You might have seen [Applicative-Monad-Proposal, AMP](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal).

Currently the [Monad of no return, MRP](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Proposal/MonadOfNoReturn) ([email-thread](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2015-September/026121.html)) is worked on, which will make 
`Monad`'s `>>` and `Applicative`'s `*>` the same. Which eventlually would make possible to say that `traverse = mapM` and `sequence = sequenceA`. But that is a long process, which will take time.

So to answer your question: *for history reasons*.